# Error al eliminar fila de datatable C#

Tags: c#, .net

Tengo un gridview de telerik donde la fuente de datos es a través de un datatable, dentro de ese gridview tengo un boton dentro de un itemTemplete para que sepa que fila he seleccionado, la fila que seleccione se va a eliminar tanto del gridview como del datatable, el problema es que me esta marcando un error

> No se puede tener acceso  a la información eliminada de una fila

ya he intentado colocar row.Delete() y si elimina el row de mi gridview la primera vez, pero no se que pasa que después al seleccionar un segundo row diferente me genera error con el mensaje de arriba, también he ocupado la instrucción AcceptChanges() pero no funciona por la misma razón del mensaje de arriba, el codigo que uso es:

```html
    protected void LinkButton1_Click(Object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        LinkButton button = sender as LinkButton;

        int deleted = (int.Parse(button.CommandArgument.ToString()));
        if (deleted != null)
        {
            DataTable dt = (DataTable)Session["grdResultados"];
            var RowNum = Convert.ToInt32(deleted);
            foreach (DataRow row in dt.Rows)
            {

                var abc = Convert.ToInt32(row["ID"].ToString());
                if (abc == RowNum)
                {        
                    row.Delete();
                    //dt.Rows.Remove(row);
                    //dt.AcceptChanges();
                }

            }
            RadGridResultados.DataSource = dt;
            RadGridResultados.DataBind();
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No me parece buena idea eliminar una fila `DataRow` dentro del `foreach`, creo que seria aconsejable atrapar la referencia a la fila en una variable y salir del `foreach` y entonces eliminarla, te dejo a continuación el codigo, pruebalo, espero que te funcione.

```
protected void LinkButton1_Click(Object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    LinkButton button = sender as LinkButton;
    int deleted = (int.Parse(button.CommandArgument.ToString()));
    if (deleted != null)
    {
        DataTable dt = (DataTable)Session["grdResultados"];
        var RowNum = Convert.ToInt32(deleted);
        DataRow rowDel = null;
        foreach (DataRow row in dt.Rows)
        {
            var abc = Convert.ToInt32(row["ID"].ToString());
            if (abc == RowNum)
            {        
                rowDel =row;
                break;
            }
        }
        if (rowDel != null)
            rowDel.Delete();
        RadGridResultados.DataSource = dt;
        RadGridResultados.DataBind();
    }
}
```

Te agradeceria que me comentaras los resultados.

Comment: gracias @EduardoReyes  ya elimina correctamente, y no me genera error, y buen consejo de tomar el valor y salir del foreach, adicional a rowDel.Delete(), le agregue para que se eliminaran rowDel.AcceptChanges()

Comment: @Ivxn Por nada amigo, estamos aquí para ayudarnos, asi de paso tambien aprendemos.